# Google Apps Script - How to enable auth/bigquery.readonly permission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to call: `SpreadsheetApp.enableBigQueryExecution()` from a Google Apps script called when my spreadsheet changes.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.enableBigQueryExecution();
   sheet.refreshAllDataSources(); 
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.enableBigQueryExecution. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly
    at onEdit(events:11:18)
```

I have already enabled this in appsscript.json:

```json
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "sheets": {
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
    ]
}
```

And have confirmed this by looking at my project overview. When I run the function manually from the editor, it works perfectly.

However, when the function is triggered from my spreadsheet, I get the same permissions error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onEdit is a simple trigger and it cannot perform operations that require permissions.  So you will need to create an installable onEdit trigger function.  Do not name it onEdit()

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me hours of troubleshooting.